# Python slicing a string into two strings at the index with a one-character overlap and return the two strings as two elements in a list

Tags: python, string

So I want to slice a string into 2 strings at a given index with a function that I wrote:

```
#FirstProj

def run(string, index):
    print(string)
    print(index)
    print(string)
    print(string[:index])
    print(string[index:])
    return()
```

It works in conjunction with this code:

```
import FirstProj

str = 'The lazy brown fox'
index = 6
myList = FirstProj.run(str,index)
print(str)
for item in myList:
    print(item)
```

The Output is suppose to be:

```
The lazy brown fox
6
The lazy brown fox
The la
azy brown fox
```

but I'm getting this:

```
The lazy brown fox
6
The lazy brown fox
The la
zy brown fox
The lazy brown fox
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In slicing a string or a list, when you do `list[<start>:<end>]` - `start` is inclusive, but `end` is exclusive. That means the value at `start` index is included in the sliced result, but it slices only till `end-1` so when you do `string[:index]` and `string[index:]` they do not have any overlapping index.

To get your result, you should do -

```
def run(string, index):
    print(string)
    print(index)
    print(string)
    print(string[:index])
    print(string[index-1:])
    return()
```

Also, if you do not want to print the complete string at the end, just comment it (or remove it). Code -

```
import FirstProj

str = 'The lazy brown fox'
index = 6
FirstProj.run(str,index)
#print(str)      <--------------- This is the line printing the string at the end, comment it.
#for item in myList:  <------------- Remove these lines as well, they do not do anything.
#    print(item)       <------------- Remove these lines as well, they do not do anything.
```

Comment: My output needs to not have the entire string at the end and I don't know how to get it without it being printed...

Comment: Yea also commet the `print(str)` after the function call.

Comment: @AnandSKumar but the function returns no value right

Comment: But does it really matter? According to what he really wants, he does not need to return anything, if he returns the items he wouldn't get the result he wants.

Answer (score 0):

You have printed the string after executing the function.Comment it and try:

```
#FirstProj
def run(string, index):
    print(string)
    print(index)
    print(string)
    print(string[:index])
    print(string[index:])
    return()
```

**The function:**

```
import FirstProj
str = 'The lazy brown fox'
index = 6
myList = FirstProj.run(str,index)
#print(str)
for item in myList:
    print(item)
```

**output:**

```
The lazy brown fox
6
The lazy brown fox
The la
zy brown fox
```

**You have returned nothing from the function just a empty return**

**Modification:**

```
#FirstProj
def run(string, index):
    return(string,index,string,string[:index],string[index:])
```

**The Function:**

```
import FirstProj
str = 'The lazy brown fox'
index = 6
myList = FirstProj.run(str,index)
#print(str)
for item in myList:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Ok but what if I don't have that option and this is the code that I need in order to run my function.  What's wrong with my function that I can't make it work...

Comment: I have and that does give me my answer but what if I can't modify that code...what if that's the code that has to stay the same and I have to modify my code in order to make it work?

Comment: The code return nothing what do you expect @zurinaK

Comment: @zurinaK provide your full requirement

Comment: @zurinaK is this what you want

Comment: I fthis question helped  then click the the tick on the lest side